# 'Not key value coding-compliant' error from deleted xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

In my project I have a ContentViewController class which initially used an xib for layout.  However, I later decided to delete the xib and programatically insert the subviews.  When I deleted one of the subviews that had initially been present, I got:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key infoView.'"

From research I know that this sort of error is almost always due to linkage issues between a class and a xib.  I already checked to make sure that no class in the workspace references infoView, so that's not the issue.  How can I unlink ContentViewController from the xib when the xib no longer exists?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you removed the app from the device and/or simulator? During a deploy from within Xcode, files in the app bundle are never deleted. So the nib file might still be present in the app bundle.

Comment: Ah yes, that also worked.  Resetting the simulator cleared it out.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch -- nice; this issue was driving me bonkers with a difference between a trunk and branch version of the app.  Tried everything *but* deleting from the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there are issues with the NIB file being deleted from inside the app, the safe way to resolve is to implement `loadView` and do your custom view creation there as this will prevent the superclass from trying to load a NIB.

Comment: Do you mean in a specific viewDidLoad: method, or just some arbitrary method that isn't init?  The latter is what I am currently doing.

Comment: You want to add the method to `ContentViewController`. It isn't an arbitrary method, it's part of the `UIViewController` loading process.

Comment: Well, I'm getting some other errors now that I'll have to figure out, but the NSUnknownKeyException went away.  Thanks!